# tools similar to yourkit?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, yourkit

I've been using yourkit, it's a great tool. I normally use the CPU consumption level curve, and thread drill-down against time.

but recently I am suspecting that yourkit is causing the random 20-seconds freeze in my application, since no excessive IO or GC is happening, and in such freeze period, the machine's CPU utilization drops down to about 5%, so it's not doing busy GC.

so I'd like a tool similar to yourkit, to try it out , to see if the issue is really due to yourkit

the following shows one freeze, you can see that the CPU usage is a straight line for the center period, that's because yourkit wasn't able to take samples during that period, in fact for that period JVM was frozen.

http://farm7.static.flickr.com/6157/6193700183_80297855d5_b.jpg

I checked that there is no stop-the-world GC in that period

thanks a lot
Yang

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[VisualVm](http://visualvm.java.net/features.html) has some of the features of yourkit.

Comment: Indeed VisualVm has the features you are talking of.

Answer (score 3):

You can try [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) (disclaimer: my company develops JProfiler). VisualVM has some basic profiling capabilities, but feature-wise it does not really compare to Yourkit or JProfiler.